# com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13

Tags: mongodb, unauthorized

We are getting `com.mongodb.MongoQueryException`:

```
> Query failed with error code 13 while connecting to MongDB trhough
> spring-data.


MongoDB version 3.x
```

`Spring 4.1.6`, `mongo-java-driver - 3.0.2`, `spring-data-commons - 1.10.0.RELEASE`, `spring-data-mongodb - 1.7.0.RELEASE`

Unable to run the find query on a collection.

I am able to view the collection on GUI using same credentials.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full exception:

```
> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query
> failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query
> on <db.table>' on server xxx; nested exception is
> com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and
> error message 'not authorized for query on db.table on server xxx
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:96)
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2002)
>     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1885)
```

Comment: from error message  'not authorized for query on ' on server xxx does your mongoDB require password

Answer (score 0):

Check mongo XSD for 2.6 vs 3.0 java drivers, they are different - it seems you still use old way to authenticate.

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.database}" username="${mongo.user}"
                  password="${mongo.pwd}" mongo-ref="mongo"/>
```

This works with 2.6 java driver only, not with 3.0 java driver.

Use this `mongo-client-option` with credentials attribute.

```
<mongo:mongo-client replica-set="${mongo.replica-set}" credentials="you need to put here user/password with specific DB">
```

The comma delimited list of `username:password@database` entries to use for authentication. Appending `? uri.authMechanism` allows to specify the authentication challenge mechanism. If the credential you're trying to pass contains a comma itself, quote it with single quotes: `'…'`.